# curl post issues: input password became empty

Tags: linux, shell, curl

I'm using "curl" to get a webpage which needs username and password.

For some webpages, I can get the page I want with expression like

```
curl -u myusername:mypassword url -o output.html.
```

But for some other webpages, I can't get the page I want.

I've tried expressions mentioned above, it seemes the username and the password is not sent with the request.

I also tried expressions like

```
curl -d"login_username=myusername&login_password=mypassword&action=login&submit=Login" url -o output.html.
```

The username is sent, but the password is still empty.

By the way, there is a "**realm: LDAP**" under username & password inputbox.

Does anybody know what is happening? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that a website uses HTTP basic authentication, a verbose mode, with -v option, makes you confirm whether the authentication request is sent or not. If the authentication request is sent, you can see Authorization header as the below.

```
$ curl -v -u user:password http://foo.example.com/auth/ -o output.html

* About to connect() to x.x.x.x port 3128
*   Trying x.x.x.x... connected
* Connected to proxy.example.com (x.x.x.x) port 3128
* Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
> GET http://foo.example.com/auth/ HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Basic cm9vdDpSaW5nMjAXMA==
```

Answer (score -1):

The syntax for cURL username & password is :

```
user,password
```

and **not**

```
user:password
```

So finally :

```
curl -s -v -u myusername,mypassword url
```

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackoverflow website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackoverflow works, thanks ;)

Comment: I tried your way, and it always request password. However, `curl -u myusername:mypassword url -o output.html` works fine, it just doesn't work for the situation I mentioned.

Comment: And I cheked the online manual. I'm sure it should be `user:password`, **not** `user,password`, see http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html for reference.